# I want a row inside a container which has a boxdecoration too

Tags: flutter-layout

Im trying to build a screen, where i want a row widget inside a container, where the container has a boxDecoration property.How do to do that ?

I tried to put the container in a sized box, which has a boxDecoration property.Now, i want a row widget so that i can put an image and some text next to each other.But i do not have any idea to do that.

This is my code :

SizedBox(
                  width: 420.0,
                  height: 110.0,

```
                child :
                Container( //here i want a row widget so that i can put one image and some text 

                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10,top:30,left:20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffD4D4D4),width: 2.0)
                  ),
                  child : Text("External LTE 4G universal modem antennas (2 or 4) (SMA) finger tighten only",textAlign: TextAlign.justify,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  )
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want an Image and some text next to each other?

Try this.

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10,top:30,left:20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffD4D4D4),width: 2.0)
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(), // <-- add the image path here, also don't forget to add the image to pubspec.yaml
                Expanded(child: Text("External LTE 4G universal modem antennas (2 or 4) (SMA) finger tighten only",textAlign: TextAlign.justify,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),))
              ],
            )
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , but if the text is long there is an overflow of text and its getting out of the box.What should i do now ?

Comment: you can surround the text Widget with a Expanded Widget. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, the expanded thing worked slightly but the text at the end of the box is not visible (like i can only see half of last letter in the sentence).

Comment: What do you mean It works perfectly for me??
Try adding this to the Container padding 
` padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10,top:30,left:20, right: 20.0),`